# How can I get a post value with $request variable in the routes

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get a value in the route my code is this one:

```
Route::post('transaction/store', 'TransactionController@store')->middleware(['apiauth:'.$request->token]);
```

I have that in routes/api.php

How can I get the token with request variable because I need to send that parameter into the middleware, but the problem is that I can not use Request $request because I do not have a function. So I wonder how can I get the post variable in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not pass the `token` via middleware like this `->middleware(['apiauth:'.$request->token]);` and you do not have to.

As the `handle` method has the `$request` object.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class MyMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // You can get the `token` here.
        // $request->token
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and for your middleware, you do `->middleware(['apiauth']);`

Here is how you send request:
[image]

Comment: But when I do I use a dd() and it is null $request->token displays null

Comment: I did what you told me exactly how told me: Route::post('transaction/store', 'TransactionController@store')->middleware(['apiauth']);  but when I use this dd($request->token); inside the middleware it returns null, and I am sending the value as post in the postman as a post field, and this field calls token

Comment: @JesúsCova see my pic, works for me. did you register the middleware correctly?